# Python tkinter and web scraping and Calling functions

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am new to python programming and working on a new tkinter application . I am stuck at a particular place. The following is my code

What i am trying to accomplish is when i click the button with command=getval. Tt will scan the page on the request. The issue that i am facing is ,my code is getting bigger and bigger and i want to use functions and call them in my main program , but i am stuck . Any suggestions ,on how to call function for the above code  .

Thanks in advance .

```
def getval():
    if len(Ent1.get()) == 0:
        print("Enter a ticker value in the block")
    else:
        ticker = str(Ent1.get())
        request = requests.get(("http://money.cnn.com/quot/quote.html?symb=") + (ticker))
        content = request.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
```

Comment: There are many examples on the web how to do this. But even most of those examples will recommend using classes and methods instead of functions. Try [this link](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html). It shows how to create a class, methods, and how to call those methods from the widgets you create.

Comment: Thank you Ron for the link , i will look into this .